# What is the origin of Machete Order?

Tags: star-wars

So after seeing [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65237/in-what-spot-would-the-new-star-wars-movie-rogue-one-go-in-the-machete-order), I got curious about "Machete Order." That question didn't explain where it came from. I tried googling "machete order" but I only got articles talking about watching Star Wars in Machete Order. I also tried searching movies.SE but I only found the previously referenced question. So I want to know:

1. What is the origin of "Machete Order"?
2. What is the reason for the name "Machete Order"?

Comment: Related: [In what order should a newcomer watch Star Wars episodes?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2063/49)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson oh I got that result but I thought it was the same as the question in my post. I'm still curious how it got that name.

Comment: Well, all you need to know is elaborated in the post linked from that question's answers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2011/11/11/the-star-wars-saga-suggested-viewing-order/ was where the order was introduced.

The name of the order is from the author Rod Hilton's blog name, "Absolutely No Machete Juggling" ([blog name origin is a cartoon about human nature, NOT about actual blades](http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/about.html))

> I've dubbed this "Machete Order" on the off chance it catches on because I'm a vain asshole. (UPDATE: It did!)

Comment: and i always thought it was called machete because it "cut" out Episode 1

Comment: also daarn that was quick :P

Comment: I actually saw that website but didn't even notice the site name. At first I thought it was somehow related to the [2010 movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machete_(film)).