# Star wars chronology

Tags: star-wars

I have not seen any Star Wars movies till date. I don't have any idea about the timeline of Star Wars but recently after the release of *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, a curiosity has been awakened in me. So I would highly appreciate if anybody can tell me the order in which I should watch these movies to get a better understanding of the Star Wars universe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In what order should a newcomer watch Star Wars episodes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/in-what-order-should-a-newcomer-watch-star-wars-episodes) & also https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65237/in-what-spot-would-the-new-star-wars-movie-rogue-one-go-in-the-machete-order

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched

Answer (score 2):

**Film & TV Series Cannon Chronology Event Order**

- Episode I: The Phantom Menace
- Episode II: Attack of the Clones
- Star Wars: The Clone Wars (Animated TV Series. New Season is coming!)
- Episode III: Revenge of the Sith
- Solo: A Star Wars Story
- Star Wars: Rebels (Animated TV Series)
- Untitled Andor Cassian Rogue One Prequel (Live Action TV Series Comming 2020 Disney +)
- Obi-Wan Mini-Series (Live Action TV Series Coming 2020 Disney+)
- Rogue One: A Star Wars Story
- Episode IV: A New Hope
- Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back
- Episode VI: Return of the Jedi
- Star Wars: Resistance (Animated TV Series. Premiers October 2018)
- Star Wars: The Mandalorian (Live Action TV Series. Premiere's November 12th 2019)
- Episode VII: The Force Awakens
- Episode VIII: The Last Jedi
- Episode IX: The Rise of Skywalker (Released December 20th 2019)

---

Note that the "Episode" films are the Skywalker [family] Saga Films. "A Star Wars Story" are anthology films, but *Solo* might have been a trilogy. There is talk of a TV series, but nothing confirmed. There are also 2 other potential trilogies: one from *The Last Jedi* Director Rian Johnson and one from *Game of Thrones* EPs, David Benioff and D. B. Weiss. And there may be film coming from Kevin Feige of *Marvel MCU* fame.

I have given the chronological event order of the films, but there are **several theories** and/or **preferences** for "best viewing", as some feel that watching them in different/non event order (such as by release date), is better than watching them in event order. But since that is opinion based, I did not specify any preference, only giving you **a layout to where everything is "suppose" to go in terms of the event history.** You can look for opinion-based preferences by doing a Google search.

In addition there are several comic and book series. Some are tie-in material that expand on the films/TV shows.

Comment: I disagree.  Watching them in the order of release introduces the basic concepts and central characters.  The prequels are intended to provide origin story.  Seeing them first would only serve to disappoint.

Comment: Everyone has their viewing preference, but I didn't take the Q as opinion based. I just listed them chronologically in terms of the actual event history order so they could see where everything is suppose to be. There are plenty of arguments and points to be made watching them in non event order, but I am not sure if that is what the Q was asking and/or still feel they should be able to see the event order and then decide on other people's preferences, including release dates.

Comment: Choosing chronology over production order is an opinion, though.

Comment: If one was writing a story they still need drafts/outlines of events before they may decide later to change the order of things they wrote. IMO this is no different. I even stated that I made a layout and pointed out that there are several ways people believe they should view the films. If someone wants to provide another answer, they can. Q specified they didn't know the timeline.

Comment: Also it doesn't matter now that this is considered a duplicate Q.

Comment: How can it be a duplicate when the other only covers they 2012?

Comment: @CrossRoads While I would agree that the answers are out of date, because most of them don't include new films made this past decade, it is same @ and this thread can still be found and is linked with that Q now.